# Evaluating $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} x\left(1-\int\limits_{-\infty}^xe^{-t^2/2}\mathrm dt\right)^{n-1} e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm dx.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let  $f(x) = x \left(1 - \Phi(x)\right)^{n-1} e^{-x^2/2}$, where $\Phi(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^xe^{-t^2/2}\mathrm dt$. I am interested in evaluating
$$ \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \mathrm dx = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} x\left(1-\int\limits_{-\infty}^xe^{-t^2/2}\mathrm dt\right)^{n-1} e^{-x^2/2}\mathrm dx.$$

I tried some numerical methods, using Taylor expansion, but I just couldn't evaluate it. Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: Well, we are looking at:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\cdot\left(1-\int_{-\infty}^x\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)\space\text{d}t\right)^{\text{n}-1}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Comment: For $n=1,2,3$, it evaluates to $0$, $-\sqrt{\pi}$, and $\sqrt{\pi}(-2+\sqrt{2\pi})$. I can't get mathematica to evaluate for $n=4$ or above though.

Comment: It reduces to computing the volume of certain orthoscheme in the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ (which is a generalization of spherical triangles). So in $n=4$, it can be expressed in terms of dilogarithm, and the situation simply gets worse as $n$ increases. On the other hand, if we want an asymptotic formula as $n\to\infty$, we are much more lucky as this integral can be related to the expectation of maximum of i.i.d. gaussian variables. There are several techniques for dealing with such quantities.

Comment: @SangchulLee. Just out of curiosity : could you elaborate the case $n=4$ ? Thanks.